# How to get the button ID of a button in SapToolbarControl?

Tags: java, toolbar, sap-gui, silktest

I have a [SapToolbarControl (MicroFocus)](http://documentation.microfocus.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.borland.silktest.silk4net.doc%2Flangref%2FSAP%2FSapToolbarControlClass_ref.html) and I want to press a button of that toolbar.

However, any of the methods [`selectButton()`](http://documentation.microfocus.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.borland.silktest.silk4net.doc%2Flangref%2FSAP%2FSelectButtonMethodSapToolbarControl_ref.html), [`selectContextButton()`](http://documentation.microfocus.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.borland.silktest.silk4net.doc%2Flangref%2FSAP%2FSelectContextButtonMethodSapToolbarControl_ref.html) or [`pressContextButton()`](http://documentation.microfocus.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.borland.silktest.silk4net.doc%2Flangref%2FSAP%2FPressContextButtonMethodSapToolbarControl_ref.html) require a parameter called `id` of type `String`.

I was unable to find out where to get the ID from.

I am using Silk4J 16 Hotfix 2 in Eclipse Luna. This also happens in Silk4J 15.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SAP automation API provides a method called `GetButtonId` which is not implemented by Silk4J. The method takes the position of the button within the toolbar as input.

You can invoke the method yourself with the following code:

```
public String getButtonId(SapToolbarControl toolbar, int position)
{
    Object[] params = new Object[1];
    params[0] = position;
    Object buttonId = toolbar.invoke("GetButtonId", params);
    return (String) buttonId;
}
```