# How to click a Button of type Menu or ButtonAndMenu in a SapToolbarControl?

Tags: java, sap-gui, silktest

I have a button in a [SapToolbarControl](http://documentation.microfocus.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.borland.silktest.silk4net.doc%2Flangref%2FSAP%2FSapToolbarControlClass_ref.html) which is of type `ToolBarButtonType.ButtonAndMenu`. I found out [how to get the ID of the button](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30998333/4136325) and I have tried the three methods [`selectContextButton()`](http://documentation.microfocus.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.borland.silktest.silk4net.doc%2Flangref%2FSAP%2FSelectContextButtonMethodSapToolbarControl_ref.html), [`selectButton()`](http://documentation.microfocus.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.borland.silktest.silk4net.doc%2Flangref%2FSAP%2FSelectButtonMethodSapToolbarControl_ref.html) and [`pressContextButton()`](http://documentation.microfocus.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.borland.silktest.silk4net.doc%2Flangref%2FSAP%2FPressContextButtonMethodSapToolbarControl_ref.html):

`selectContextButton()` always throws a `UnsupportedMethodException` with the message

> The method SapToolbarControl::SelectContextButton is not supported for SAP.

The other two methods do not throw an exception but do nothing.

**How can I make use of toolbar control buttons of type `Menu` and `ButtonAndMenu`?**

I'm using Silk4J 16.0 Hotfix 2 in Eclipse Luna 4.4.2 with SAPGui 7.30.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clicking the button programmatically does not create the visual effect of opening a context menu, but after clicking the button, the context menu exists from which an item can be selected, e.g. with the method [`selectContextMenuItemByText()`](http://documentation.microfocus.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.borland.silktest.silk4net.doc%2Flangref%2FSAP%2FSelectContextMenuItemByTextMethodISapContextMenuable_ref.html).

`selectContextMenuItemByText()` takes the translated human readable text as a parameter which you can see when pressing the button manually (which creates the visual effect of opening a context menu).